# Loop through doctrine object from query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am tryin to get values from a doctrine query.

This is what i get in my result:

```
array(1) 
{ [0]=> object(Pdb\Backend\MenuBundle\Entity\PdbSidemenu)#759 (3) 
 { ["pdbMenuId":"Pdb\Backend\MenuBundle\Entity\PdbSidemenu":private]=> int(1) 
   ["pdbMenuName":"Pdb\Backend\MenuBundle\Entity\PdbSidemenu":private]=> string(8) "blabla" 
   ["pdbMenuIcon":"Pdb\Backend\MenuBundle\Entity\PdbSidemenu":private]=> string(7) "blabla" 
 } 
}
```

How can i loop through this?

Comment: `foreach ($results as $entity) { $entity->getPdbMenuId(); }` ?

Comment: If you have getters set up correctly in your entity, for instance, `$object->getPdbMenuId()`

Comment: Your attributes are private, you should probably add getters in your entity to access them, then you can do: $pdbSideMenu->getPdbMenuId() to get pdbMenuId value.

Comment: What's your query and how do you get this array?

Comment: Thanks for helping guys. The answer of Wissem helped me fix this problem.